# Period in a man page?

Tags: manpage, troff

I have a bold line, followed by a line starting with a period. `man` thinks that the `.` is the start of a command... is there a way to "escape" it?

```
.B bold words
./something
```

The `./something` is a command to type in a terminal, not a `man` macro. I want `man` to display it.

Things I've tried: `../something` `\./something`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the GNU Troff manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Requests.html), you should put `\&` in front of a period that should not be interpreted as the beginning of a command, i.e.

```
.B bold words
\&./something
```